# Compiling 32 Bit Application on 64 Bit Linux

Tags: c, linux, 32-bit

I'm trying to compile a program for 32 bit on a 64 bit [`Kali Linux`](https://www.kali.org/) operating system.

Here is my system information:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.18.0-kali3-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.18.6-1~kali2 (2015-03-02)
```

When I try to compile my [`C`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) project, it cannot find `-lgcc`:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/Project# make
cc -o libor libor.c -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -m32 -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Note that I'm using the `-m32` flag to force compilation for 32 bit.

Like suggested elsewhere, the 32 bit libraries should be installed which I did using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
```

This however only changed the error message to the one seen above. I lost the previous one however I guess it no longer matters.

Please note that existing answers didn't help me so this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` ?

Comment: @EugeniuRosca:
`E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate`
I get that message a lot

Comment: export CFLAGS=-m32 ?

Comment: Make sure you have both `glibc-32bit` and both `glibc-devel-32bit` and `glibc-devel-static` packages (if Kali spits the full `glibc` packages into subpackages. This will support both the static and dynamic linking. You also need to 32-bit versions of any libraries you intend to link into your executable (e.g. `libgtk-2_0-0-32bit`).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you likely only have the gcc for your current architecture and that's 64bit. You need the 32bit support files. For that, you need to install them

```
sudo apt install gcc-multilib
```

Once installed, run the below command to compile c-program to 32-bit binary executable

```
gcc -o libor libor.c -m32
```

Verify the binary is 32-bit or not by

```
file libor
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ensuring that your new 32-bit libraries are in the library search path. You can verify this by using the `ldconfig` command, and if the libraries' directories aren't listed, then use the tips in this web page: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-setting-changing-library-path/

I don't know that the above is the cause of your problem, but it may be worth a try?

Answer (score -1):

```
apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

should do the trick.